# Set/change bibliography title in RMarkdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, pdflatex

I'm currently experimenting with RMarkdown. However, I would like to change the title of my bibliography. I'm using natbib in this situation. The current RMarkdown setup is shown below:

```
title: ....
author: ....
output:
  pdf_document:
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: Referanser2.bib
biblio-style: unsrt
header_includes: 
- \usepackage{amsmath}
- \usepackage{kbordermatrix}
- \setcitationstyle{numbers,square} 
[@MyReference]
```

This gives me a simple PDF with 1 reference and a bibliography. Is there any modification which can be done to the code in order for me to change the bibliography title?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you got a typo in your YAML: it is `header-includes` with an hyphen.

You can change the head of the reference section by redefining `\refname`:

```
---
title: "Test"
author: "Martin"
header-includes: 
  - \renewcommand\refname{NEW TITLE}
output:
  pdf_document:
    keep_tex: yes
    citation_package: natbib
bibliography: skeleton.bib
biblio-style: unsrt
---

[@SomeRef]
```