# R Markdown: change the title of the "References" section?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am writing a report with R Markdown in which I include references. The problem is that R markdown automatically includes references at the end of the report (without calling them with `\printbibliography` for example) and the section title is "References". I am writing in French so I would like the title to be "Références", but more generally is there any way to modify the title of that section?

Below is reproducible example:

```
---
title:
author:
date: 
abstract: 

output: 
  pdf_document:
    template: NULL
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: bwl-FU
---

# Partie 1

\cite{greenwood_financial_1989}

# Partie 2

bla bla
```

and here is the content of the `references.bib` file:

```
@article{greenwood_financial_1989,
  title = {Financial Development, Growth and the Distribution of Income},
  url = {https://www.nber.org/papers/w3189},
  number = {3189},
  journaltitle = {NBER Working Paper Series},
  date = {1989},
  author = {Greenwood, Jeremy and Jovanovic, Boyan}
}
```

Does anybody have a solution?

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49463602/4325492)?

Comment: actually the solution in the link you provided works but only with ```natbib```, not with ```biblatex``` so I'm searching for a solution that works with ```biblatex```

Comment: Ah, okay. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994) answer at the TeX Stackexchange might be helpful then. In your `header-includes` I think adding `- \DefineBibliographyStrings{french}{bibliography = {Références}, references = Références},}` should work

Comment: I have a typo there - "Références" should be enclosed in {} both times.

Comment: I have an error: ```! Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \DefineBibliographyStrings```, even when I add ```\usepackage{babel}``` and ```\usepackage{csquotes}```

Comment: You should add `lang: fr` to your YAML header to get localized names for special section (toc, references, ...) but also language adapted hyphenation. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54676107/changing-chapter-x-name-in-bookdown-pdf/54709919#54709919

Comment: adding ```lang: fr``` in the YAML (without changing anything of the reproducible example in my post) works, thanks ! If you want, you can put it as a solution and I will validate it

Comment: Oh I misread your comment! @RalfStubner should get the credit for the solution. Out of curiosity, does the `\DefineBibliographyStrings` work to all in combination with setting the language? In pure LaTeX it works for me with the backend set to use biber.

Comment: No I always get the same error about undefined control sequence (like above). Indeed I didn't check the name because I thought it was @RalfStubner who wrote the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution that combines [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49464422/4325492) answer on doing something similar with bibtex and [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82994) one on the TeX required to do it in biblatex, plus @Ralf's comment about adding `lang: fr`

```
---
title:
author:
date: 
abstract: 

output: 
  pdf_document:
    template: NULL
    number_sections: true
    citation_package: biblatex
bibliography: references.bib
biblio-style: bwl-FU

lang: fr
---
```

Answer (score 1):

In my document, I used :

```
header-includes:
  - \usepackage[french]{babel}
```

And your Contents section also changes.

Comment: it works too but I can't validate two answers, thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem I wanted to place the bibliography above a supplemental section and placing `<div id = "refs"></div>` where you want the references successfully repositioned the section. I also had no problem renaming the section by simply changing the `# title` above that section. This did work for PDF output as well as HTML despite appearing to be an HTML only solution, though I was also using the markdown flavored (`[@Smith2019]`) references in the body of my document I don't know if using the LaTeX style will affect things.

Comment: that does not work for me, but I can't figure out why